# Can you add non-word custom vocabulary (police siren/car horn) to the Google Speech to text?

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to make a custom speech-to-text algorithm/vocabulary where things such as car horns, alarms, sirens are transcribed to text. Can Google Speech to Text do that?

Also, if Google can't do that, are there other cloud-based speech-to-text algorithms that do have that ability?

Answer (score 0):

I will limit my answer to your first question:

As far as I know, this is not supported by Speech To Text API, since it explicitly tries to have as less ambient sound as possible so that human voice recognition can be as clean as possible.

Therefore, it seems that it would go against the main goal of this algorithm/API to identify ambient sounds to transcribe them (the main interest is to identify them to remove them).